# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table already did the rake test prepare

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am learning Ruby at a boot camp. This weekend has been crazy, and I got this error in the terminal. Tried to troubleshoot the issue. Deleted Gemfile, reinstall the bundle. Even redid the whole table, still not letting me pass. Keep showing up as `Could not find the table` — Searched Google about this issue. Seems like most of the developers already on the Rails, as a beginner I would appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

I tried all of this

```
rake db:reset
rake db:migrate # Migrated each time after created the file
rake db:test:prepare # even I tried to reload the test 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'costume_stores'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:397:in `table_structure'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:113:in `columns'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:69:in `columns'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:75:in `columns_hash'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:466:in `load_schema!'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:234:in `load_schema!'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:51:in `load_schema!'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:459:in `block in load_schema'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:456:in `load_schema'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:346:in `attribute_types'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:230:in `has_attribute?'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:55:in `new'
     # /Users/akramhelil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:35:in `create'
     # ./spec/costume_store_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It's test-based app

Comment: What does your migration file look like?

Comment: I have three files in the migrate folder, due to adding two columns(which is the test required to do so), whenever I added a file I did process the migration. It was successful, but in the end, I ran the test, in total 21 examples, 15 is still failing, if I was not correctly migrating, there's a possibility that there were none of the tests are passing. I don't understand it where it went wrong :(  I spend the whole day, reinstall the ruby, reinstall the bundle, deleted the whole folder, redid the test 3 times, still not passing. I have no idea what is going on :(

Comment: What happens when you `bundle exec rake db:setup`?